# Range() function of python

Tags: python

```
for number in range(1,101):
    if number % 3 ==0 and number % 5 ==0:
        print("fizzbuzz")
    elif number %3 == 0:
        print("fizz")
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz")
```

what is the expected output as I'm not able to get the expected one can someone please help me as I'm a beginner.

The output for should be as 1 2 fizz 4 buzz fizz and so on .

Comment: You're missing `else: print(number)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that output, you just need another else:

```
for number in range(1, 101):
    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        print("fizzbuzz")
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        print("fizz")
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in range(1,101):
    if number % 3 ==0 and number % 5 ==0:
        print("fizzbuzz")
    elif number %3 == 0:
        print("fizz")
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz")
    # add this statement
    else: 
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `end` argument in `print` from default newline to space so print is on the same line.

```
for count in range(1, 101):
    result = ''
    if count % 3 == 0: result += 'Fizz'
    if count % 5 == 0: result += 'Buzz'
    print(result or count, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two complementary approaches to do this. You may use only one or both, depending on your context and skills.

## TL ; DR

This is the output after fixing the syntax errors:

```
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizzbuzz
fizz
buzz
fizz
fizz
buzz
```

## 1. Static analysis

This is basically reading the code, trying to understand what it does, without executing it. If you are a beginner, you can use a notepad or a pen and a paper to take notes, it's helpful. You can also add comments to help you remember what the code does.

Sometimes, it helps to try to explain the code to someone (imaginary or real).

Don't forget to use a search engine and the official documentation.

Let's do this together.

```py
for number in range(1,101):
```

This creates a loop:

- in which the `number` variable starts at `1`, up to `101`
- each loop increments `number` by `1` (this is the default behavior)
- each loop executes the actions (code) of the code block bellow (notice the indentation):

```py
    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
```

In Python language, `%` is the operator for the modulus. Which is the remainder from the division of the first argument (here, `number`) by the second (here, `3` or `5`).

`if` evaluates if a boolean condition (can be `True` or `False`):

Does `number % 3` **and** `number % 5` **both** equals to zero? Or said differently: is the current value in `number` a multiple of `3` and `5`?

Since there is a `and` boolean operator, both expressions need to evaluate to `True` for the underlying block of code to be executed:
`print("fizzbuzz")`, which this displays `fizzbuzz` on the output.

Then we have another condition, this time `elif`. Meaning that it will only verify this condition if the previous one did not evaluate to true (`elif` stands for **Else, if**).

```py
    elif number % 3 == 0:`your text`
        print("fizz")
```

Does `number % 3` equals to zero? Or, said differently: is the current value in `number` a multiple of 3? If so, it outputs `fizz` and leave the condition block, if not, it prints nothing and continues.

Note : this is not a correct syntax: `` elif number %3 == 0:`your text` ``  and will throw an error at execution. You probably want to remove `` `your text` ``

Following is another `elif` condition:

```py
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz"
```

Does `number % 5` equals to zero? Or, said differently: is the current value in `number` a multiple of 5? If so, it outputs `buzz` and leave the condition block, if not, it prints nothing and continues.
This is the last line of the block of code of the loop, so it goes back to the beginning of the loop (unless it reached the value `101`).

Note : this is not a correct syntax: `print("buzz"`. It is missing a closing parenthesis. You probably want to fix it like this: `print("buzz")`

After fixing the typos, add some comment (I added many), so you understand what's happening:

```py
# Loops 100 times from 1 to 101
for number in range(1,101):
    # Is the current value of number multiple of 3 and 5?
    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        print("fizzbuzz")    # if so, print fizzbuzz and leave the if
    # If previous condition fails, is number multiple of 3 ?
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        print("fizz")    # if so, print fizz and leave the if
    # If previous condition fails, is number multiple of 3 ?
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz")    # if so, print fizz and leave the if
    # loop code is finished, if between 1 and 101, continue to loop
```

Now try to synthesize ; this code:

- loops from 1 to 100

  - prints `fizzbuzz` when `number` is only a mutiple of both `3` and `5`
  - prints `fizz` when `number` is only a mutiple of both `3`
  - prints `buzz` when `number` is only a mutiple of both `5`
  - does nothing / prints nothing in all other cases

## 2. Dynamic analysis

This is another approach in which you execute the code to understand what it does. You can use the script's behavior (ouputs, results, errors, etc.) to understand what it does.

Let's put your code in a file called `script.py` and execute it:

```bash
python3 script.py
  File "script.py", line 4
    elif number % 3 == 0:`your text`
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The interpreter could not execute your script. It gives you a clue of where the issue is:

- line 4 in `script.py`
- the problematic line of code: `` elif number %3 == 0:`your text` ``
- the place in the line (pointed by `^`)
- a generic error name and explanation: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, which means there is a typo or something which prevents the Python interpreter to understand your code.

Indeed, the `:` should be followed by a new line. Even if you had put a new line, `your text` is not some valid python code.

Let fix it: `elif number %3 == 0:`and run it again.

```bash
python3 script.py
  File "script.py", line 7
    print("buzz"
         ^
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed
```

We now have an error at line 7. Meaning that it went a bit further this time. Once again, the error gives you clues:

- at line 7 in `script.py`
- the problematic line of code: `print("buzz"`
- the place in the line (pointed by `^`)
- once again, a syntax error.

Indeed, you never closed the `(` you open to call the `print` function. Let fix it: `print("buzz")` and run it again. It works! (see TL ; DR section).

## Bonus

When using both static and dynamic analysis for a small code, in addition to comments, you can modify the code to better understand how it works, for example by printing more information. For big projects, using a debugger is better.

Here is a version of the code that will print the current version of number and the result (fizzbuzz, fizz or buzz):

`script.py`

```py
# Modified version
for number in range(1,101):
    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        print(str(number) + " --> fizzbuzz")
    elif number %3 == 0:
        print(str(number) + " -> fizz")
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print(str(number) + " -> buzz")
```

Output:

```
3 -> fizz
5 -> buzz
6 -> fizz
9 -> fizz
10 -> buzz
12 -> fizz
15 --> fizzbuzz
18 -> fizz
20 -> buzz
21 -> fizz
24 -> fizz
25 -> buzz
27 -> fizz
30 --> fizzbuzz
33 -> fizz
35 -> buzz
36 -> fizz
39 -> fizz
40 -> buzz
42 -> fizz
45 --> fizzbuzz
48 -> fizz
50 -> buzz
51 -> fizz
54 -> fizz
55 -> buzz
57 -> fizz
60 --> fizzbuzz
63 -> fizz
65 -> buzz
66 -> fizz
69 -> fizz
70 -> buzz
72 -> fizz
75 --> fizzbuzz
78 -> fizz
80 -> buzz
81 -> fizz
84 -> fizz
85 -> buzz
87 -> fizz
90 --> fizzbuzz
93 -> fizz
95 -> buzz
96 -> fizz
99 -> fizz
100 -> buzz
```